# Underscore template - show first item in an array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I've inherited an Underscore template like this:

```
<script type="text/template" id="tpl-post">
    <div class="ti-author-box">
    <% _.each(authors, function(author) { %>
        <% if ( author.author_image ) { %>
            <img class="ti-author-image" src="<%= author.author_image %>" alt="<%= author.author_display_name %>" />
        <% } else { %>
            <img class="ti-author-image" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/default-user.png?resize=40%2C40" alt="<%= author.author_display_name %>" />
        <% } %>
        <div class="ti-author-name" ><%= author.author_display_name %></div> 
    <% }); %>
    </div>

    ...

</script>
```

`authors` is an array of authors, with each element an object which has properties like `author_image` and `author_display_name`.

My question is, how can I change this to just show the info for the first author in the array, instead of looping through the array with _.each()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just add the 0 array index like:

```
<% if ( author[0].author_image ) { %>
   <img class="ti-author-image" src="<%= author[0].author_image %>" alt="<%= author[0].author_display_name %>" />
   <% } else { %>
       <img class="ti-author-image" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/default-user.png?resize=40%2C40" alt="<%= author[0].author_display_name %>" />
   <% } %>
   <div class="ti-author-name" ><%= author[0].author_display_name %></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Both yours and Juhana's are the right answers, so I'm ticking the earliest.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to pick just the first element of the array.

```
<script type="text/template" id="tpl-post">
    <div class="ti-author-box">
    <% var author = authors[0]; %>
    <% if ( author.author_image ) { %>
        <img class="ti-author-image" src="<%= author.author_image %>" alt="<%= author.author_display_name %>" />
    <% } else { %>
        <img class="ti-author-image" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/default-user.png?resize=40%2C40" alt="<%= author.author_display_name %>" />
    <% } %>
    <div class="ti-author-name" ><%= author.author_display_name %></div> 

    </div>

    ...

</script>
```